# Using a class inside an Interface file from another package

Tags: java, eclipse, scope

I have two packages. The first one contains an empty interface and a class implementing it in a single file ("IThing" and "Thing"). The second one contains another Interface ("IThingUser") which has a function returning an object of the type "Thing".

When both files are part of the same package everything works fine, but if they are in two separate packages the one in package2 cannot access the class defined in the first package.

Package1 contains the following file :

```
package project.package1;

public interface IThing {
}

final class Thing implements IThing {

    private int thingField;

    public int thingFieldGetter(){
        return thingField;
    }
}
```

And package2 has :

```
package project.package2;

import project.package1.IThing;

public interface IThingUser {

    public IThing someFunction(); // Works fine

    public Thing anotherFunction();
    // "Thing" is not recognized when the two files are in separate packages.
}
```

**Why does this happen ? Is there a way to fix this issue while keeping this architecture ?**

PS : I know the structure of this does not make much sense but I did not code package1 and I have to use it as-is.

Comment: You're missing the `Thing` import?

Comment: Why do you make your `Thing` implement an empty interface? Do you know what interfaces are meant to be used for?

Comment: The Import alone won't be enough... Look at the default visibility of `Thing`

Comment: @deHaar there are various reasons to create/implement empty interfaces. (E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)

Comment: @ParkerHalo very good point, I was only aware of the Critique point in the article you linked, but there may be reasons. That is what I can admit now ;-) Thanks

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn "Thing" and "IThing" are in a single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `project.package1.Thing` is **not visible outside the package** `project.package1`, but **public classes** must be defined **in their own files**.

Answer (score 0):

Class `Thing` has package-private visibility. You wouldn't be able to access it outside `project.package1` package until it will be implemented as

```
public final class Thing implements IThing
```

Comment: which is not possible in the same file as the interface!